# Using local tangent plane projection in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

Is local tangent plane projection is a kind of gnomonic projection?
is it possible to define it as a custom projection in QGis?

Comment: A local tangent plane is closer to orthographic but is often based on an ellipsoid rather than a sphere (most orthographic implementations are sphere-only).

Comment: The Z axis of local tanget plane is oriented such that it pass through the center of the earth, so I think it is more close to gnomonic projection.